# Connecting to redis in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have installed a module node-redis (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) locally in my express application. I added node-redis to my package.json and ran npm install. The module got installed. But if i start the node REPL and do

```
var redis = require("redis")
```

I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'redis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

How can i fix this?

Thank You

Comment: "I added node-redis..." – Might be I misunderstand but if you wrote "node-redis" in your package-json it should be just "redis".

Comment: @AndreasHultgren if you look closely, you'll see that the module is, in fact, `redis`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine If I look closely where? I can't see his package.json. It seems very plausible to me that one might mistakenly write the wrong name and not notice the error since there's also the [node-redis](https://npmjs.org/package/node-redis) module.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren if you look closely at the link he showed: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the node REPL in a folder where it can look for the `redis` package. If you installed `redis` in your local installation, be sure to run the node REPL from the local installation folder.

For example, if you installed `redis` in `C:\Users\Jim\Projects\project1`, you need to run node after `cd`ing into this folder.

On a side note, learn how to use `npm install redis --save`. This will install `redis` locally, and add the dependency in your package.json file.